# Как выбрать ширину каждой картинки javascript-ом

Tags: jquery, javascript, изображения

Есть картинки в списке, я я подсчитываю сколько картинок,

```
var countimg =  $("#images ul li").size();
```

потом делаю счетчик

```
var i = 0;

for(i; i < countimg; i++){

  var widthimg = $("#images img").eq(i).width();

}
```

Думаю со счетчиком проблемы, подскажите, как подсчитать ширину каждой картинки.

Comment: Пропущена точка перед eq()

Answer (score 2):

```
var _list = $("#images ul li");
var arrImgWidth = _list.map(function(i,el){
    return $(el).find('img').width();
}).get();
```

P.S. Вместо метода **.size()**, используйте **length**, т.к. начиная с версии 1.8, этот метод считается устаревшим.

Comment: ошибок нету, но чисто, данных нету

Comment: Вы что-то упустили. Т.к. [всё работает нормально](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/b7BBN/). Проверьте на ошибки, оберните код:    $(function(){        // Тутачки код    });

Answer (score 1):

```
var array_width = [];
$("#images ul img").each(function(){
   array_width.push($(this).width());
});
```

пробуй так

Comment: я пробовал так, выводит [object object]

Comment: array_width - это массив с ширинами картинок. Если ты выводил alert(array_width), то оно все правильно показало. Массив по сути тоже является объектом в JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrWidth;
$("#images ul li").each(function(el){
    arrWidth.push( $(el).find('img').width() );
});
```

Так будет работать во всех браузерах. Метод .map не работает в IE7

Comment: метод map это метод библиотеки jQuery.

Comment: буду знать, полезная штука =)

Comment: @lampa, в чистом JS тоже есть метод map()